# Delphi - Capture stdout and stderr output from statically linked MSVC++ compiled DLL

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, stdout, stderr

I have been trying to capture *stdout* and *stderr* output from a DLL compiled in MSVC++ that my Delphi app statically links to, but so far have been unsuccessful.

```
procedure Test;
var
  fs: TFileStream;

begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create('C:\temp\output.log', fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite);
  SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, fs.Handle);
  SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, fs.Handle);

  dllFunc(0); // Writes to stdout in MSVC++ console app, but not here
  // fs.Length is always zero

  fs.Free;
end;
```

Thought I was on the right track, but it does not work.

1. Is SetStdHandle() enough?
2. Is TFileStream the right thing to use here?
3. Am I using TFileStream properly for SetStdHandle()?
4. Is it possible that the DLL sets its stdout/stderr handles when the app loads?  If so, where is the best place to use SetStdHandle() or equivalent?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: fmShareDenyWrite does not work with fmCreate - it is simply useless.
fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite = fmCreate.

Comment: Interesting Serg, yeah I see that fmCreate has a value of 0xFFFF which would make any share mode flags useless. Odd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the DLL grabs the stdout handles when it is loaded, then you will need to dynamically load the DLL after you have changed the stdout handles in your code.

Comment: Definitely a good point, although even now that I load the DLL dynamically (after calling SetStdHandle), I still get no output.

Comment: dthorpe, your recommendation worked (I just was not seeing it). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a console app, you could just run the thing and capture everything to stdout with redirection.  i.e.

```
C:\MyAppWhichCallsDll.exe > c:\temp\output.log
```